# Histograms too different compared to how they should be

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, bar-chart, find-occurrences

I have a black/white image `I0` (512 x 512) to which I have to remove the first `k` pixel and calculate the histogram of the resulting image.

Let me explain: I have to build the histogram of the image `I0` without considering the first `k` pixels.

This is my code:

```
k = 8;

% compute the histogram of the entire image I0
[vecComp, histComp] = histKtoEnd(I0, 0, k);

% compute the histogram of the image I0 without the first k pixel    
[vecWithoutKPixel, histWithoutKPixel] = histKtoEnd(I0, k, k);
```

where:

```
function [vecWithoutKPixel, hist] = histKtoEnd(image, k, colorDepth)
    % image to row vector
    imageVec = reshape(image.', [], 1);
    l = length(imageVec); 

    % I "delete" the first k pixel
    vecWithoutKPixel = imageVec((k+1) : l-1);
    vecWithoutKPixel(end+1) = imageVec(l); 

    % inizialization
    hist = zeros(1, 2^colorDepth); 

    % create the vector of occurrences
    for i = 0 : (2^colorDepth - 1) 
        grayI = (vecWithoutKPixel == i);
        hist(1, i+1) = sum(grayI(:));
    end
end
```

To display the two histograms do:

```
subplot(1, 2, 1);
bar(0:2^k-1, histComp, 'r'); 
title('Histogram of the entire image'); 
axis([minColor, maxColor, 0, numberOfPixels]);
subplot(1, 2, 2);
bar(0:2^k-1, histWithoutKPixel, 'r'); 
title('Histogram of the image without the first k pixels'); 
axis([minColor, maxColor, 0, numberOfPixels]);
```

and I get:
[image]

As you can see, the histograms are very different, yet should differ very little since the difference is only 8 pixels.

Where am I wrong?

Also in warkspace the newly created variables have these dimensions:

```
vecComp -> 262144 x 1 uint8
histComp -> 1 x 256 double
vecWithoutKPixel -> 65528 x 1 uint8
histWithoutKPixel -> 1 x 256 double
```

This is very strange. I should have:

```
vecComp -> 262144 x 1
vecWithoutKPixel -> 262136 x 1
```

Could someone help me?
Thank you

---

I'm working with DICOM images and the command `info = dicominfo(filename)` get

```
size = info.FileSize; % 262582; 
colorType = info.ColorType; % grayscale
```

So I don't think that the problem is the image.

If I put a brakpoint on line `vecWithoutKPixel(end+1) = imageVec(l);` I get that `imageVec` is 262144 x 1 uint8, and:

```
function [vecWithoutKPixel, hist] = histKtoEnd(image, k, colorDepth)
    % image to row vector
    imageVec = reshape(image.', [], 1);
    l = length(imageVec); 

    size(imageVec) % 262144 x 1

    % I "delete" the first k pixel
    vecWithoutKPixel = imageVec((k+1) : l-1);
    vecWithoutKPixel(end+1) = imageVec(l); 

    % inizialization
    hist = zeros(1, 2^colorDepth); 

    % create the vector of occurrences
    for i = 0 : (2^colorDepth - 1) 
        grayI = (vecWithoutKPixel == i);
        hist(1, i+1) = sum(grayI(:));
    end
end
```

If I change the commands `vecWithoutKPixel = imageVec((k+1) : l-1); 
vecWithoutKPixel(end+1) = imageVec(l);` with `vecWithoutKPixel = imageVec((k+1) : l);` I get that `vecWithoutKPixel = []`.

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint on the line `vecWithoutKPixel = imageVec((k+1) : l-1);` and check the dimension of `imageVec` using `size(imageVec)`? Also 1) `(k+1) : (l-1)` might be different and 2) Why did you "delete" the last element and then put it back?

Comment: And try `imageVec = image(:);`

Comment: Well the real problem is in your image data. I believe you are dealing with a B/W picture, but it is stored as a RGBA image in Matlab. This can be seen by the size of the original image. You have to convert it to true B/W at first.

Comment: @Yvon Thanks for the reply! I edited my main question.

Comment: `vecComp` length is `262144`, and `vecWithoutKPixel` length is `65528`. Instead of removing 8 elements, you removed `262144 - 65528` elements. You mentioned `I0` is (256 x 256), so number of elements should be `256* 256` = `65536`, yet you are getting `262144`. `256*256*4` = `262144`. In case resolution is 256x256, there are 4 elements per pixel (likely RGBA format like Yoav mentioned).

Comment: When I tried to reproduce your problem (using RGBA input), I am getting an error in `reshape(image.', [], 1);`. I suspect bug might be involved with Matlab 2016b new feature called [implicit expansion](https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/). Are you using Matlab 2016b? (I am using an older version).

Comment: @Rotem Sorry I misspelled, in reality the picture is 512x512 (not 256x256). I'm using Matlab 2014b.

Comment: Your first image shows 60,000 pixels in the first bin (brightness=0 on left side of histogram) and the second one shows 25,000 pixels in the first bin so you have removed more than the 8 pixels you claim.

Comment: @valerie So how come `vecWithoutKPixel` length is only `65528` (when it should be `262136`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a 'random-image' using `I0=randi(255,100,100)` and then running your code will produce a plot like this:
[image: Histogram of randomly created image]
I guees this plot looks exactly like it should and the dimensions of the variables are correct as well:

```
vecComp 10000x1 double
vecWithoutKPixel 9992x1 double
```

Thus our problem is not actually your code, but your image. Your image is not really gray level valued which has been mentioned by others before. But instead of casting some variables to `uint8` like @Richard suggested, you should cast your image to double. If your image is rgb valued use `I0=double(rgb2gray(I0));` or if it is just `uint8`  for some other reason use `I0=double(I0)` and then pass it to the function. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the image data is originally in `uint8` format and gets converted to `double` at some point. Therefore, the line

```
grayI = (vecWithoutKPixel == i);
```

in `histKtoEnd` probably only works with the `uint8` data ( since you compare the data with an integer).

Try adding the line

```
vecWithoutKPixel = uint8(vecWithoutKPixel);
```

to the `histKtoEnd` function:

```
function [vecWithoutKPixel, hist] = histKtoEnd(image, k, colorDepth)
    % image to row vector
    imageVec = reshape(image.', [], 1);
    l = length(imageVec); 

    % I "delete" the first k pixel
    vecWithoutKPixel = imageVec((k+1) : l-1);
    vecWithoutKPixel(end+1) = imageVec(l); 

    % inizialization
    hist = zeros(1, 2^colorDepth); 

    % create the vector of occurrences
    for i = 0 : (2^colorDepth - 1) 
        vecWithoutKPixel = uint8(vecWithoutKPixel);  % Cast to integer
        grayI = (vecWithoutKPixel == i);
        hist(1, i+1) = sum(grayI(:));
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried to apply the changes you suggested but I always have the same problem...